# How to extract only real part of 2nd root solution to C code?

Tags: complex, polynomials

I have this cubic polynomial:

```
-a^2 + a b + a c - 
 b c + (4 a - 2 a^2 - 2 b - 2 c + 2 b c + a^2 k - a b k - a c k + 
    b c k) x + (-3 + 2 a + 2 b - a b + 2 c - a c - b c - 2 a k + b k +
     a b k + c k + a c k - 2 b c k) x^2 + (k - b k - c k + b c k) x^3
```

Is it possible in Mathematica to somehow get equation for only Real part of 2nd root assuming all Real numbers and a>1, b>1, c>1, 0 < k < 3 , x > 1 ? I would like to convert this equation to C code and export it (but without using Complex classes etc.)

**UPDATE**

this is second root, and since it contains this I imaginary part, I cannot transfer it easily to C code and calculate only real part of solution. Is it possible somehow to rewrite following equation as R*x+I*y and then just remove I*y part and use only R*X part?

e.g. for values `a=2`, `b=4`, `c=4`, `k=1.11` I get `1.84213 + 4.16334*10^-17 I`, but I need only `1.84213`.

```
-((3 - 2 a - 2 b + a b - 2 c + a c + b c + 2 a k - b k - a b k - c k -
    a c k + 2 b c k)/(
  3 (-k + b k + c k - 
     b c k))) + ((1 + 
      I Sqrt[3]) (3 (-k + b k + c k - b c k) (-4 a + 2 a^2 + 2 b + 
         2 c - 2 b c - a^2 k + a b k + a c k - b c k) - (3 - 2 a - 
        2 b + a b - 2 c + a c + b c + 2 a k - b k - a b k - c k - 
        a c k + 2 b c k)^2))/(3 2^(
    2/3) (-k + b k + c k - b c k) (-54 + 108 a - 72 a^2 + 16 a^3 + 
      108 b - 198 a b + 120 a^2 b - 24 a^3 b - 72 b^2 + 120 a b^2 - 
      66 a^2 b^2 + 12 a^3 b^2 + 16 b^3 - 24 a b^3 + 12 a^2 b^3 - 
      2 a^3 b^3 + 108 c - 198 a c + 120 a^2 c - 24 a^3 c - 198 b c + 
      312 a b c - 156 a^2 b c + 24 a^3 b c + 120 b^2 c - 
      156 a b^2 c + 60 a^2 b^2 c - 6 a^3 b^2 c - 24 b^3 c + 
      24 a b^3 c - 6 a^2 b^3 c - 72 c^2 + 120 a c^2 - 66 a^2 c^2 + 
      12 a^3 c^2 + 120 b c^2 - 156 a b c^2 + 60 a^2 b c^2 - 
      6 a^3 b c^2 - 66 b^2 c^2 + 60 a b^2 c^2 - 12 a^2 b^2 c^2 + 
      12 b^3 c^2 - 6 a b^3 c^2 + 16 c^3 - 24 a c^3 + 12 a^2 c^3 - 
      2 a^3 c^3 - 24 b c^3 + 24 a b c^3 - 6 a^2 b c^3 + 12 b^2 c^3 - 
      6 a b^2 c^3 - 2 b^3 c^3 + 18 a^2 k - 12 a^3 k - 18 a b k - 
      18 a^2 b k + 18 a^3 b k + 18 b^2 k - 18 a b^2 k + 
      36 a^2 b^2 k - 18 a^3 b^2 k - 12 b^3 k + 18 a b^3 k - 
      18 a^2 b^3 k + 6 a^3 b^3 k - 18 a c k - 18 a^2 c k + 
      18 a^3 c k - 18 b c k + 144 a b c k - 72 a^2 b c k - 
      18 b^2 c k - 72 a b^2 c k + 36 a^2 b^2 c k + 18 b^3 c k + 
      18 c^2 k - 18 a c^2 k + 36 a^2 c^2 k - 18 a^3 c^2 k - 
      18 b c^2 k - 72 a b c^2 k + 36 a^2 b c^2 k + 36 b^2 c^2 k + 
      36 a b^2 c^2 k - 18 a^2 b^2 c^2 k - 18 b^3 c^2 k - 12 c^3 k + 
      18 a c^3 k - 18 a^2 c^3 k + 6 a^3 c^3 k + 18 b c^3 k - 
      18 b^2 c^3 k + 6 b^3 c^3 k - 6 a^3 k^2 + 9 a^2 b k^2 + 
      9 a^3 b k^2 + 9 a b^2 k^2 - 36 a^2 b^2 k^2 + 9 a^3 b^2 k^2 - 
      6 b^3 k^2 + 9 a b^3 k^2 + 9 a^2 b^3 k^2 - 6 a^3 b^3 k^2 + 
      9 a^2 c k^2 + 9 a^3 c k^2 - 36 a b c k^2 + 18 a^2 b c k^2 - 
      36 a^3 b c k^2 + 9 b^2 c k^2 + 18 a b^2 c k^2 + 
      18 a^2 b^2 c k^2 + 9 a^3 b^2 c k^2 + 9 b^3 c k^2 - 
      36 a b^3 c k^2 + 9 a^2 b^3 c k^2 + 9 a c^2 k^2 - 
      36 a^2 c^2 k^2 + 9 a^3 c^2 k^2 + 9 b c^2 k^2 + 18 a b c^2 k^2 + 
      18 a^2 b c^2 k^2 + 9 a^3 b c^2 k^2 - 36 b^2 c^2 k^2 + 
      18 a b^2 c^2 k^2 - 36 a^2 b^2 c^2 k^2 + 9 b^3 c^2 k^2 + 
      9 a b^3 c^2 k^2 - 6 c^3 k^2 + 9 a c^3 k^2 + 9 a^2 c^3 k^2 - 
      6 a^3 c^3 k^2 + 9 b c^3 k^2 - 36 a b c^3 k^2 + 
      9 a^2 b c^3 k^2 + 9 b^2 c^3 k^2 + 9 a b^2 c^3 k^2 - 
      6 b^3 c^3 k^2 + 2 a^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 b k^3 - 3 a^3 b k^3 - 
      3 a b^2 k^3 + 12 a^2 b^2 k^3 - 3 a^3 b^2 k^3 + 2 b^3 k^3 - 
      3 a b^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 b^3 k^3 + 2 a^3 b^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 c k^3 - 
      3 a^3 c k^3 + 12 a b c k^3 - 6 a^2 b c k^3 + 12 a^3 b c k^3 - 
      3 b^2 c k^3 - 6 a b^2 c k^3 - 6 a^2 b^2 c k^3 - 
      3 a^3 b^2 c k^3 - 3 b^3 c k^3 + 12 a b^3 c k^3 - 
      3 a^2 b^3 c k^3 - 3 a c^2 k^3 + 12 a^2 c^2 k^3 - 
      3 a^3 c^2 k^3 - 3 b c^2 k^3 - 6 a b c^2 k^3 - 6 a^2 b c^2 k^3 - 
      3 a^3 b c^2 k^3 + 12 b^2 c^2 k^3 - 6 a b^2 c^2 k^3 + 
      12 a^2 b^2 c^2 k^3 - 3 b^3 c^2 k^3 - 3 a b^3 c^2 k^3 + 
      2 c^3 k^3 - 3 a c^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 c^3 k^3 + 2 a^3 c^3 k^3 - 
      3 b c^3 k^3 + 12 a b c^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 b c^3 k^3 - 
      3 b^2 c^3 k^3 - 3 a b^2 c^3 k^3 + 
      2 b^3 c^3 k^3 + \[Sqrt]((-54 + 108 a - 72 a^2 + 16 a^3 + 
           108 b - 198 a b + 120 a^2 b - 24 a^3 b - 72 b^2 + 
           120 a b^2 - 66 a^2 b^2 + 12 a^3 b^2 + 16 b^3 - 24 a b^3 + 
           12 a^2 b^3 - 2 a^3 b^3 + 108 c - 198 a c + 120 a^2 c - 
           24 a^3 c - 198 b c + 312 a b c - 156 a^2 b c + 
           24 a^3 b c + 120 b^2 c - 156 a b^2 c + 60 a^2 b^2 c - 
           6 a^3 b^2 c - 24 b^3 c + 24 a b^3 c - 6 a^2 b^3 c - 
           72 c^2 + 120 a c^2 - 66 a^2 c^2 + 12 a^3 c^2 + 120 b c^2 - 
           156 a b c^2 + 60 a^2 b c^2 - 6 a^3 b c^2 - 66 b^2 c^2 + 
           60 a b^2 c^2 - 12 a^2 b^2 c^2 + 12 b^3 c^2 - 6 a b^3 c^2 + 
           16 c^3 - 24 a c^3 + 12 a^2 c^3 - 2 a^3 c^3 - 24 b c^3 + 
           24 a b c^3 - 6 a^2 b c^3 + 12 b^2 c^3 - 6 a b^2 c^3 - 
           2 b^3 c^3 + 18 a^2 k - 12 a^3 k - 18 a b k - 18 a^2 b k + 
           18 a^3 b k + 18 b^2 k - 18 a b^2 k + 36 a^2 b^2 k - 
           18 a^3 b^2 k - 12 b^3 k + 18 a b^3 k - 18 a^2 b^3 k + 
           6 a^3 b^3 k - 18 a c k - 18 a^2 c k + 18 a^3 c k - 
           18 b c k + 144 a b c k - 72 a^2 b c k - 18 b^2 c k - 
           72 a b^2 c k + 36 a^2 b^2 c k + 18 b^3 c k + 18 c^2 k - 
           18 a c^2 k + 36 a^2 c^2 k - 18 a^3 c^2 k - 18 b c^2 k - 
           72 a b c^2 k + 36 a^2 b c^2 k + 36 b^2 c^2 k + 
           36 a b^2 c^2 k - 18 a^2 b^2 c^2 k - 18 b^3 c^2 k - 
           12 c^3 k + 18 a c^3 k - 18 a^2 c^3 k + 6 a^3 c^3 k + 
           18 b c^3 k - 18 b^2 c^3 k + 6 b^3 c^3 k - 6 a^3 k^2 + 
           9 a^2 b k^2 + 9 a^3 b k^2 + 9 a b^2 k^2 - 36 a^2 b^2 k^2 + 
           9 a^3 b^2 k^2 - 6 b^3 k^2 + 9 a b^3 k^2 + 9 a^2 b^3 k^2 - 
           6 a^3 b^3 k^2 + 9 a^2 c k^2 + 9 a^3 c k^2 - 36 a b c k^2 + 
           18 a^2 b c k^2 - 36 a^3 b c k^2 + 9 b^2 c k^2 + 
           18 a b^2 c k^2 + 18 a^2 b^2 c k^2 + 9 a^3 b^2 c k^2 + 
           9 b^3 c k^2 - 36 a b^3 c k^2 + 9 a^2 b^3 c k^2 + 
           9 a c^2 k^2 - 36 a^2 c^2 k^2 + 9 a^3 c^2 k^2 + 
           9 b c^2 k^2 + 18 a b c^2 k^2 + 18 a^2 b c^2 k^2 + 
           9 a^3 b c^2 k^2 - 36 b^2 c^2 k^2 + 18 a b^2 c^2 k^2 - 
           36 a^2 b^2 c^2 k^2 + 9 b^3 c^2 k^2 + 9 a b^3 c^2 k^2 - 
           6 c^3 k^2 + 9 a c^3 k^2 + 9 a^2 c^3 k^2 - 6 a^3 c^3 k^2 + 
           9 b c^3 k^2 - 36 a b c^3 k^2 + 9 a^2 b c^3 k^2 + 
           9 b^2 c^3 k^2 + 9 a b^2 c^3 k^2 - 6 b^3 c^3 k^2 + 
           2 a^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 b k^3 - 3 a^3 b k^3 - 3 a b^2 k^3 + 
           12 a^2 b^2 k^3 - 3 a^3 b^2 k^3 + 2 b^3 k^3 - 3 a b^3 k^3 - 
           3 a^2 b^3 k^3 + 2 a^3 b^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 c k^3 - 
           3 a^3 c k^3 + 12 a b c k^3 - 6 a^2 b c k^3 + 
           12 a^3 b c k^3 - 3 b^2 c k^3 - 6 a b^2 c k^3 - 
           6 a^2 b^2 c k^3 - 3 a^3 b^2 c k^3 - 3 b^3 c k^3 + 
           12 a b^3 c k^3 - 3 a^2 b^3 c k^3 - 3 a c^2 k^3 + 
           12 a^2 c^2 k^3 - 3 a^3 c^2 k^3 - 3 b c^2 k^3 - 
           6 a b c^2 k^3 - 6 a^2 b c^2 k^3 - 3 a^3 b c^2 k^3 + 
           12 b^2 c^2 k^3 - 6 a b^2 c^2 k^3 + 12 a^2 b^2 c^2 k^3 - 
           3 b^3 c^2 k^3 - 3 a b^3 c^2 k^3 + 2 c^3 k^3 - 
           3 a c^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 c^3 k^3 + 2 a^3 c^3 k^3 - 
           3 b c^3 k^3 + 12 a b c^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 b c^3 k^3 - 
           3 b^2 c^3 k^3 - 3 a b^2 c^3 k^3 + 2 b^3 c^3 k^3)^2 + 
         4 (3 (-k + b k + c k - b c k) (-4 a + 2 a^2 + 2 b + 2 c - 
               2 b c - a^2 k + a b k + a c k - b c k) - (3 - 2 a - 
              2 b + a b - 2 c + a c + b c + 2 a k - b k - a b k - 
              c k - a c k + 2 b c k)^2)^3))^(
    1/3)) - ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-54 + 108 a - 72 a^2 + 16 a^3 + 108 b - 
      198 a b + 120 a^2 b - 24 a^3 b - 72 b^2 + 120 a b^2 - 
      66 a^2 b^2 + 12 a^3 b^2 + 16 b^3 - 24 a b^3 + 12 a^2 b^3 - 
      2 a^3 b^3 + 108 c - 198 a c + 120 a^2 c - 24 a^3 c - 198 b c + 
      312 a b c - 156 a^2 b c + 24 a^3 b c + 120 b^2 c - 
      156 a b^2 c + 60 a^2 b^2 c - 6 a^3 b^2 c - 24 b^3 c + 
      24 a b^3 c - 6 a^2 b^3 c - 72 c^2 + 120 a c^2 - 66 a^2 c^2 + 
      12 a^3 c^2 + 120 b c^2 - 156 a b c^2 + 60 a^2 b c^2 - 
      6 a^3 b c^2 - 66 b^2 c^2 + 60 a b^2 c^2 - 12 a^2 b^2 c^2 + 
      12 b^3 c^2 - 6 a b^3 c^2 + 16 c^3 - 24 a c^3 + 12 a^2 c^3 - 
      2 a^3 c^3 - 24 b c^3 + 24 a b c^3 - 6 a^2 b c^3 + 12 b^2 c^3 - 
      6 a b^2 c^3 - 2 b^3 c^3 + 18 a^2 k - 12 a^3 k - 18 a b k - 
      18 a^2 b k + 18 a^3 b k + 18 b^2 k - 18 a b^2 k + 
      36 a^2 b^2 k - 18 a^3 b^2 k - 12 b^3 k + 18 a b^3 k - 
      18 a^2 b^3 k + 6 a^3 b^3 k - 18 a c k - 18 a^2 c k + 
      18 a^3 c k - 18 b c k + 144 a b c k - 72 a^2 b c k - 
      18 b^2 c k - 72 a b^2 c k + 36 a^2 b^2 c k + 18 b^3 c k + 
      18 c^2 k - 18 a c^2 k + 36 a^2 c^2 k - 18 a^3 c^2 k - 
      18 b c^2 k - 72 a b c^2 k + 36 a^2 b c^2 k + 36 b^2 c^2 k + 
      36 a b^2 c^2 k - 18 a^2 b^2 c^2 k - 18 b^3 c^2 k - 12 c^3 k + 
      18 a c^3 k - 18 a^2 c^3 k + 6 a^3 c^3 k + 18 b c^3 k - 
      18 b^2 c^3 k + 6 b^3 c^3 k - 6 a^3 k^2 + 9 a^2 b k^2 + 
      9 a^3 b k^2 + 9 a b^2 k^2 - 36 a^2 b^2 k^2 + 9 a^3 b^2 k^2 - 
      6 b^3 k^2 + 9 a b^3 k^2 + 9 a^2 b^3 k^2 - 6 a^3 b^3 k^2 + 
      9 a^2 c k^2 + 9 a^3 c k^2 - 36 a b c k^2 + 18 a^2 b c k^2 - 
      36 a^3 b c k^2 + 9 b^2 c k^2 + 18 a b^2 c k^2 + 
      18 a^2 b^2 c k^2 + 9 a^3 b^2 c k^2 + 9 b^3 c k^2 - 
      36 a b^3 c k^2 + 9 a^2 b^3 c k^2 + 9 a c^2 k^2 - 
      36 a^2 c^2 k^2 + 9 a^3 c^2 k^2 + 9 b c^2 k^2 + 18 a b c^2 k^2 + 
      18 a^2 b c^2 k^2 + 9 a^3 b c^2 k^2 - 36 b^2 c^2 k^2 + 
      18 a b^2 c^2 k^2 - 36 a^2 b^2 c^2 k^2 + 9 b^3 c^2 k^2 + 
      9 a b^3 c^2 k^2 - 6 c^3 k^2 + 9 a c^3 k^2 + 9 a^2 c^3 k^2 - 
      6 a^3 c^3 k^2 + 9 b c^3 k^2 - 36 a b c^3 k^2 + 
      9 a^2 b c^3 k^2 + 9 b^2 c^3 k^2 + 9 a b^2 c^3 k^2 - 
      6 b^3 c^3 k^2 + 2 a^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 b k^3 - 3 a^3 b k^3 - 
      3 a b^2 k^3 + 12 a^2 b^2 k^3 - 3 a^3 b^2 k^3 + 2 b^3 k^3 - 
      3 a b^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 b^3 k^3 + 2 a^3 b^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 c k^3 - 
      3 a^3 c k^3 + 12 a b c k^3 - 6 a^2 b c k^3 + 12 a^3 b c k^3 - 
      3 b^2 c k^3 - 6 a b^2 c k^3 - 6 a^2 b^2 c k^3 - 
      3 a^3 b^2 c k^3 - 3 b^3 c k^3 + 12 a b^3 c k^3 - 
      3 a^2 b^3 c k^3 - 3 a c^2 k^3 + 12 a^2 c^2 k^3 - 
      3 a^3 c^2 k^3 - 3 b c^2 k^3 - 6 a b c^2 k^3 - 6 a^2 b c^2 k^3 - 
      3 a^3 b c^2 k^3 + 12 b^2 c^2 k^3 - 6 a b^2 c^2 k^3 + 
      12 a^2 b^2 c^2 k^3 - 3 b^3 c^2 k^3 - 3 a b^3 c^2 k^3 + 
      2 c^3 k^3 - 3 a c^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 c^3 k^3 + 2 a^3 c^3 k^3 - 
      3 b c^3 k^3 + 12 a b c^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 b c^3 k^3 - 
      3 b^2 c^3 k^3 - 3 a b^2 c^3 k^3 + 
      2 b^3 c^3 k^3 + \[Sqrt]((-54 + 108 a - 72 a^2 + 16 a^3 + 
           108 b - 198 a b + 120 a^2 b - 24 a^3 b - 72 b^2 + 
           120 a b^2 - 66 a^2 b^2 + 12 a^3 b^2 + 16 b^3 - 24 a b^3 + 
           12 a^2 b^3 - 2 a^3 b^3 + 108 c - 198 a c + 120 a^2 c - 
           24 a^3 c - 198 b c + 312 a b c - 156 a^2 b c + 
           24 a^3 b c + 120 b^2 c - 156 a b^2 c + 60 a^2 b^2 c - 
           6 a^3 b^2 c - 24 b^3 c + 24 a b^3 c - 6 a^2 b^3 c - 
           72 c^2 + 120 a c^2 - 66 a^2 c^2 + 12 a^3 c^2 + 120 b c^2 - 
           156 a b c^2 + 60 a^2 b c^2 - 6 a^3 b c^2 - 66 b^2 c^2 + 
           60 a b^2 c^2 - 12 a^2 b^2 c^2 + 12 b^3 c^2 - 6 a b^3 c^2 + 
           16 c^3 - 24 a c^3 + 12 a^2 c^3 - 2 a^3 c^3 - 24 b c^3 + 
           24 a b c^3 - 6 a^2 b c^3 + 12 b^2 c^3 - 6 a b^2 c^3 - 
           2 b^3 c^3 + 18 a^2 k - 12 a^3 k - 18 a b k - 18 a^2 b k + 
           18 a^3 b k + 18 b^2 k - 18 a b^2 k + 36 a^2 b^2 k - 
           18 a^3 b^2 k - 12 b^3 k + 18 a b^3 k - 18 a^2 b^3 k + 
           6 a^3 b^3 k - 18 a c k - 18 a^2 c k + 18 a^3 c k - 
           18 b c k + 144 a b c k - 72 a^2 b c k - 18 b^2 c k - 
           72 a b^2 c k + 36 a^2 b^2 c k + 18 b^3 c k + 18 c^2 k - 
           18 a c^2 k + 36 a^2 c^2 k - 18 a^3 c^2 k - 18 b c^2 k - 
           72 a b c^2 k + 36 a^2 b c^2 k + 36 b^2 c^2 k + 
           36 a b^2 c^2 k - 18 a^2 b^2 c^2 k - 18 b^3 c^2 k - 
           12 c^3 k + 18 a c^3 k - 18 a^2 c^3 k + 6 a^3 c^3 k + 
           18 b c^3 k - 18 b^2 c^3 k + 6 b^3 c^3 k - 6 a^3 k^2 + 
           9 a^2 b k^2 + 9 a^3 b k^2 + 9 a b^2 k^2 - 36 a^2 b^2 k^2 + 
           9 a^3 b^2 k^2 - 6 b^3 k^2 + 9 a b^3 k^2 + 9 a^2 b^3 k^2 - 
           6 a^3 b^3 k^2 + 9 a^2 c k^2 + 9 a^3 c k^2 - 36 a b c k^2 + 
           18 a^2 b c k^2 - 36 a^3 b c k^2 + 9 b^2 c k^2 + 
           18 a b^2 c k^2 + 18 a^2 b^2 c k^2 + 9 a^3 b^2 c k^2 + 
           9 b^3 c k^2 - 36 a b^3 c k^2 + 9 a^2 b^3 c k^2 + 
           9 a c^2 k^2 - 36 a^2 c^2 k^2 + 9 a^3 c^2 k^2 + 
           9 b c^2 k^2 + 18 a b c^2 k^2 + 18 a^2 b c^2 k^2 + 
           9 a^3 b c^2 k^2 - 36 b^2 c^2 k^2 + 18 a b^2 c^2 k^2 - 
           36 a^2 b^2 c^2 k^2 + 9 b^3 c^2 k^2 + 9 a b^3 c^2 k^2 - 
           6 c^3 k^2 + 9 a c^3 k^2 + 9 a^2 c^3 k^2 - 6 a^3 c^3 k^2 + 
           9 b c^3 k^2 - 36 a b c^3 k^2 + 9 a^2 b c^3 k^2 + 
           9 b^2 c^3 k^2 + 9 a b^2 c^3 k^2 - 6 b^3 c^3 k^2 + 
           2 a^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 b k^3 - 3 a^3 b k^3 - 3 a b^2 k^3 + 
           12 a^2 b^2 k^3 - 3 a^3 b^2 k^3 + 2 b^3 k^3 - 3 a b^3 k^3 - 
           3 a^2 b^3 k^3 + 2 a^3 b^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 c k^3 - 
           3 a^3 c k^3 + 12 a b c k^3 - 6 a^2 b c k^3 + 
           12 a^3 b c k^3 - 3 b^2 c k^3 - 6 a b^2 c k^3 - 
           6 a^2 b^2 c k^3 - 3 a^3 b^2 c k^3 - 3 b^3 c k^3 + 
           12 a b^3 c k^3 - 3 a^2 b^3 c k^3 - 3 a c^2 k^3 + 
           12 a^2 c^2 k^3 - 3 a^3 c^2 k^3 - 3 b c^2 k^3 - 
           6 a b c^2 k^3 - 6 a^2 b c^2 k^3 - 3 a^3 b c^2 k^3 + 
           12 b^2 c^2 k^3 - 6 a b^2 c^2 k^3 + 12 a^2 b^2 c^2 k^3 - 
           3 b^3 c^2 k^3 - 3 a b^3 c^2 k^3 + 2 c^3 k^3 - 
           3 a c^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 c^3 k^3 + 2 a^3 c^3 k^3 - 
           3 b c^3 k^3 + 12 a b c^3 k^3 - 3 a^2 b c^3 k^3 - 
           3 b^2 c^3 k^3 - 3 a b^2 c^3 k^3 + 2 b^3 c^3 k^3)^2 + 
         4 (3 (-k + b k + c k - b c k) (-4 a + 2 a^2 + 2 b + 2 c - 
               2 b c - a^2 k + a b k + a c k - b c k) - (3 - 2 a - 
              2 b + a b - 2 c + a c + b c + 2 a k - b k - a b k - 
              c k - a c k + 2 b c k)^2)^3))^(1/3))/(6 2^(
    1/3) (-k + b k + c k - b c k))
```

Comment: which one is the "second" root?

Comment: Hi Bojan, you need to put a bit more in your question. Explain better what you need, share the code you have tried already and why it doesn't answer you needs. Share all the necessary information for somebody to reproduce your problem, don't make us guess. Show explicitly what is wrong and what you expect in detail. Learn about [good questions here](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform OK, I just updated code

Comment: @rhermans Any reason for using link shorteners? I don't think it's OK to expect people to click on your URLs without knowing where they'll take them...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano_formula. The discrimanants that are built for Cardanos formula allow you to decide at runtime which roots will be real and to produce only those.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform good point, I do have my reasons that may be argued and we could discuss in the [chat], I made [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96458/about-using-url-shorteners-in-comments)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher from this page I can see I need p and q, but what to do with constants with X^2 and X^3? They are not needed?

Comment: @BojanVukasovic That's solved by transforming the polynomial to depressed form first: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Reduction_to_a_depressed_cubicTha

Comment: In C it would be much easier to call the corresponding [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) function [gsl_poly_complex_solve_cubic](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/poly.html#cubic-equations). No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher just looked at the wiki page. I already know which root will be always real... but cannot code it in C since it has this imaginary part in equation. If I could somehow group this, and use just R part it would be easy to convert to C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I found an answer with help from above comments (this is only for one root that I need):

```
public static double[] solveCubicOnly2nd(double d, double a, double b, double c) {
        if (d != 1) {
            a = a / d;
            b = b / d;
            c = c / d;
        }

        double p = b / 3 - a * a / 9;
        double q = a * a * a / 27 - a * b / 6 + c / 2;

        double ang = Math.acos(-q / Math.sqrt(-p * p * p));
        double r = 2 * Math.sqrt(-p);

        double theta = ang / 3;
        double rez = r * Math.cos(theta);
        rez = rez - a / 3;


        return new double[] {rez};
    }
```

where params are as: `d * x^3 + a * x^2 + b * x + c = 0`

And if you need all roots:

```
public static double[] solveCubic(double d, double a, double b, double c) {
        double[] result;
        if (d != 1) {
            a = a / d;
            b = b / d;
            c = c / d;
        }

        double p = b / 3 - a * a / 9;
        double q = a * a * a / 27 - a * b / 6 + c / 2;
        double D = p * p * p + q * q;

        if (Double.compare(D, 0) >= 0) {
            if (Double.compare(D, 0) == 0) {
                double r = Math.cbrt(-q);
                result = new double[2];
                result[0] = 2 * r;
                result[1] = -r;
            } else {
                double r = Math.cbrt(-q + Math.sqrt(D));
                double s = Math.cbrt(-q - Math.sqrt(D));
                result = new double[1];
                result[0] = r + s;
            }
        } else {
            double ang = Math.acos(-q / Math.sqrt(-p * p * p));
            double r = 2 * Math.sqrt(-p);
            result = new double[3];
            for (int k = -1; k <= 1; k++) {
                double theta = (ang - 2 * Math.PI * k) / 3;
                result[k + 1] = r * Math.cos(theta);
            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = result[i] - a / 3;
        }
        return result;
    }
```